# How to connect to flask server via android

Tags: python, android, flask

Regarding to the above topic, I have build a flask program to control the GPIO of board:

```
def readall():
    for i in PINS: 
        pin = PINS[i]['pin']
        alt=gpio.getAlt(pin)
        #if DEBUG == 1: print("i={} pin={} alt={}".format(i, pin, alt))
        value=gpio.digitalRead(pin)
        #if DEBUG == 1: print("pin={} alt={} value={}".format(pin, ALTS[alt], value))
        PINS[i]['mode']=alt
        PINS[i]['smode']=ALTS[alt]
        PINS[i]['value']=value

    for i in PINS: 
        if DEBUG == 1: print("i={} mode={} smode={}".format(i, PINS[i]['mode'], PINS[i]['smode']))

@app.route("/")
def main():
    # For each pin, read the pin state and store it in the pins dictionary:
    templateData = {
        'pins' : PINS
    }
    # Pass the template data into the template main.html and return it to the user
    return render_template('webioOP.html', **templateData)

# change pin mode
@app.route("/changeMode/<int:changePin>/<action>")
def actionMode(changePin, action):
    if DEBUG == 1: print("actionMode: changePin={} action={}".format(changePin, action))
    # Convert the pin from the URL into an integer:
    #cpin = int(changePin)
    pin = PINS[changePin]['pin']

    # Get the device name for the pin being changed:
    deviceName = PINS[changePin]['name']
    if DEBUG == 1: print("pin={} deviceName={}".format(pin, deviceName))
    # If the action part of the URL is "output," execute the code indented below:
    if action == "output":
        # Set the pin output:
        gpio.pinMode(pin, OUTPUT)
        # Save the status message to be passed into the template:
        message = "Turned " + deviceName + " output."
    if action == "input":
        gpio.pinMode(pin, INPUT)
        message = "Turned " + deviceName + " input."

    readall()

    # Along with the pin dictionary, put the message into the template data dictionary:
    templateData = {
        'message' : message,
        'pins' : PINS
    }

    return render_template('webioOP.html', **templateData)


# change output value
@app.route("/changeValue/<int:changePin>/<action>")
def actionValue(changePin, action):
    if DEBUG == 1: print("actionValue: changePin={} action={}".format(changePin, action))
    # Convert the pin from the URL into an integer:
    #cpin = int(changePin)
    pin = PINS[changePin]['pin']

    # Get the device name for the pin being changed:
    deviceName = PINS[changePin]['name']
    if DEBUG == 1: print("pin={} deviceName={}".format(pin, deviceName))
    # If the action part of the URL is "on," execute the code indented below:
    if action == "on":
        # Set the pin high:
        gpio.digitalWrite(pin, HIGH)
        # Save the status message to be passed into the template:
        message = "Turned " + deviceName + " on."
    if action == "off":
        gpio.digitalWrite(pin, LOW)
        message = "Turned " + deviceName + " off."
    if action == "toggle":
        # Read the pin and set it to whatever it isn't (that is, toggle it):
        value=wringpi.digitalRead(pin)
        gpio.digitalWrite(pin, not value)
        message = "Toggled " + deviceName + "."

    readall()

    # Along with the pin dictionary, put the message into the template data dictionary:
    templateData = {
        'message' : message,
        'pins' : PINS
    }

    return render_template('tlx.html', **templateData)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gpio.wiringPiSetupPhys()
    readall()
    if DEBUG == 1: app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
    if DEBUG == 0: app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=False)
```

the question is, how can I connect to the server via androidNetworkController? The androidNetworkController have been built and the IP address and port of the Debian's flask server have been written in the AndrodiNetworkController.

```
package com.example.nfc;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class AndroidNetworkController {

    // Replace with the actual IP address and port of the Debian OS or Flask server
    private static final String DEBIAN_OS_IP = "192.168.0.56";
    private static final int DEBIAN_OS_PORT = 80;

    // Endpoint paths for starting and stopping GPIO operations
    private static final String START_GPIO_ENDPOINT = "/start_gpio";
    private static final String STOP_GPIO_ENDPOINT = "/stop_gpio";

    public void sendDataToDebian(String data) {
        // Replace with the actual URL of your Debian OS
        String debianOsUrl = "http://" + DEBIAN_OS_IP + ":" + DEBIAN_OS_PORT;

        // Send data to Debian OS
        sendHttpPostRequest(debianOsUrl, data);
    }
```

But somehow, the android application cannot be launched. is it because the flask server is not available at that time? because the flask application is not activated?

Comment: my android application successfully send command to debian via network. :)